# Python: list indexing behaving abnormally, returns newly generated string instead of item

Tags: python, python-3.9

I've been working on a python game where the objective is to move `x//2` Ts from the left to the right, and `x//2` Fs from the right to the left. `x` is a user inputted odd integer.

There is a dash `-` between the two groups. The user is supposed to enter a number, `n`
and the program should move the F or T in place `n` to the empty space, the one with a dash. the Ts can only move 1 or 2 spaces to the right, and the Fs can only move 1 or 2 spaces to the left.

If the 2 spaces the F or T can move to are both occupied, the program will print "Invalid entry!" and will ask for `n` again. Now the place where the problem is is the undo option.

The game should be able to undo to the beginning. I created the list `record`. Now when I added the part where it gets the item, instead it created a new string (or something). I changed the program to print `record` but there's nothing wrong with it. Does anybody know whats happening? My code's below.

```
boardsize = int(input())
board = "T"*(boardsize//2)+"-"+"F"*(boardsize//2)
finish = "F"*(boardsize//2)+"-"+"T"*(boardsize//2)
record = [board]
moves = 0
shouldpass = False

print("\n"+board, end = "")

while board != finish:
    move = int(input())-1
    if move == -1 and moves>0:
        board = record[moves-1]
        moves -= 2
        shouldpass = True
    while (move<0 or move>=boardsize) or (board[move]=="T" and move+1!=board.find("-") and move+2!=board.find("-")) or (board[move]=="F" and move-1!=board.find("-") and move-2!=board.find("-")) or (board[move]=="-"):
        if shouldpass:
            break
        move = int(input("\nInvalid entry!\n"))-1

    moves+=1
    board = list(board)
    board[board.index("-")] = board[move]
    board[move] = "-"
    board = "".join(board)
    print("\n")
    print(board)
    print("Number of moves:\n"+str(moves))
    record.append(board)

print("\nYou win!")
```

Comment: `record` just grows and grows and grows.  Shouldn't you be popping the last element off the end so that it doesn't get reused?

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do. ```record``` is supposed to be a list full of all steps of the board, from step 0 to the last step.

Comment: Try the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide?

Comment: BTW, instead of `shouldpass = True` you probably want `continue` on that line, to go straight to the next iteration of the loop

Comment: oops i forgot to add a break/pass

Comment: yes, i could try that, but i want to make it so that the program displays the things as normal right after.

Comment: BTW I think I fixed it.